# new Date(long) gives different results

Tags: java, date, timezone

When I run this code:

```
System.out.println( "XXX date=" + new Date( 1311781583373L ) );
```

I get this result in Eclipse's JUnit runner:

```
XXX date=Wed Jul 27 16:46:23 GMT+01:00 2011
```

and this result in Maven from the command line:

```
XXX date=Wed Jul 27 17:46:23 CEST 2011
```

As you can see, the hour is different.

(same computer, same Java version, maybe 30s apart). Why?

**[EDIT]** Also the time zone is different. Why is Java using `CEST` when it's started from Maven and `GMT+01:00` when started from Eclipse?

Or to put it another way: How can I force Java to use either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To specify the default timezone you can set the system property `user.timezone`. You can do this by passing it as an argument to the JavaVM (you may need to modify eclipse.ini or Maven equivalent config file):

```
-Duser.timezone=<your preferred timezone>
```

...or by setting it programmatically:

```
 System.setProperty("user.timezone", "<your preferred timezone>");
```

Or, if it is convenient you can specify a timezone which you use each time you print out the date:

```
DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("<insert date format string here>");    
myDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("<your preferred timezone>")); 
....
System.out.println(myDateFormat.format(yourDate));
```

Comment: For the record: Java 6 is smarter to figure out the time zone than Java 5. I made Maven use Java 6 in `.mavenrc`

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Maven and Eclipse have picked up different default time zones, that's all.

Don't forget that `Date.toString()` uses the default time zone. I would personally prefer to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) and probably log the UTC value instead of a local time :)

Comment: How does Java determine the default time zone? I'm not aware that I gave Eclipse different Java time zone settings than Maven.

Comment: As you can see in the output, the time zone info is different. How do I solve this? Legacy code, so Joda Time isn't an option.

Comment: @Aaron: You can force Eclipse to use a specific time zone when starting a binary by specifying it in the environment. You can probably do the same thing with Eclipse, but it's unclear which is "correct" in your case, or indeed why they differ.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());
```

before calculating the date. It should display different time zones. And the default time zone is based on the locale your JVM uses. You can force the JVM to use the locale of your preference by supplying it with the following parameters:

```
$ java -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=CA
```

In Maven you can use `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable. Also [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml) is an article describing how to change your locale permanently on Windows.

Comment: When running Java, the value of `user.timezone` is different. In Eclipse, it's `US`. In Maven, it's `Europe/Zurich`. `user.country` is always `US`.