# java.util.date time is different than the system time

Tags: java, date, timezone

My system time is 12:23 AM, but if i try to display the time using normal java code;

```
Date dt = new Date();
System.out.println("date is "+dt);
```

i am getting different time :  `date is Mon Sep 05 01:23:18 BDST 2011`
Help me out.

Comment: Maybe problem with time zone? Please,look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981890/new-datelong-gives-different-results

Comment: daylight saving time issues maybe

Comment: I think it may be a daylight saving time issue . How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jdk 6 has problem with date. When i installed jdk 7 problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Is it correct now?

```
Date dt = new Date();
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(dt));
```

Is `BDST` (*British Double Summer Time*) your time zone (GMT +01:00)?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little convoluted but you could do the following (obviously substitute your time zone):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles") );
Date dt = cal.getTime();

System.out.println( dt);
```

I've not tried it but I have a feeling this might work! `Date` will always initialise to UTC.

Answer (score -1):

This may help...

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateUtils {
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

    public static String now() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    }

    public static void  main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.println("Now : " + DateUtils.now());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Diptopol Dam Updated the answer.

Comment: Just adding in SimpleDateFormat doesn't change the value of the date.