# Maven uses timezone which differ from system

Tags: java, linux, maven, timezone

I'm faced with strange problem: Maven shows different time than system. For example:

```
$ mvn compile | grep Finished
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 04 13:29:50 NOVT 2012
$ LANG=C date
Wed Jan  4 14:29:55 NOVT 2012
```

Here Maven's time differs to 1 hour back.

I've googled and found very similar question here, at SO: [new Date(long) gives different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981890/new-datelong-gives-different-results) but none of suggested ways doesn't work for me: specifying `-Duser.timezone=Asia/Novosibirsk` or `-Duser.language=ru` and `-Duser.country=RU` do not affects Maven's behavior.

I think the problem at underlying system's tzdata, because at previours year we stop to moving hours from summer time. I've installed latest `tzdata-java` package but nothing changed.

Versions:

- maven 3.0.3
- debian 6.0.1
- `tzdata`/`tzdata-java` 2011n-0squeeze1

BTW, in my IDE (Springsource Tool Suite) I've similar problem.

Thanks in advance!

(And feel free to remove one or more tags which is not really relevant to problem.)

Comment: What does just `date` return on your system?

Comment: Your maven output shows the Novosibirsk time: because "Wed Jan  4 14:29:55 NOVT 2012
" in here, NOVT means Novosibisk Time Zone. I think the problem is latest changes done to your time zone, not a Maven issue.

Comment: Ins't the time shown by maven the correct one? Have you tried updating your system timezone data?

Comment: @mat No, Maven's date is incorrect. And yes, I've tried to update `tzdata` package.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, most of the users will have to wait until Sun will re-release time zones info for Java with corrected daylight savings, MS will release Windows patch, and the same for Linux.

Comment: Ultimately all of these layers of code have to rely on calling tzset().  You can force tzset() to return correct results by defining the TZ variable correctly for your timezone, usually in a file like /etc/profile.  Then remove the other environmental TZ references until you get a tzdata fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully fix this by running `tzupdater` and patch installed JDK.

More about [Timezone Updater Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html).