# the SimpleDateFormat issues on different servers

Tags: java, simpledateformat

My code has a problem, and I just found the reason, but don't know how to fix it.
When I ran the following code on my laptop:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
long processingTime = df.parse("2013-05-20").getTime();
System.out.println(processingTime);
```

the output is:

```
1369033200000
```

But when I run the same code in Amazon Server, 
the output is:

```
1369008000000
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could this be due to different time zones and/or locale settings on the two machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the timezone. Better use the joda library, at is far better suited for date operations:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.2

Take a look at :

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

And specify the timezone and locale.

You can take a look at this similiar question:
[new Date(long) gives different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981890/new-datelong-gives-different-results)

Edit:

I wrote a unit test for you:

```
    @Test
    public void testPattern(){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                .withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
                .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        long time = formatter.parseDateTime("2013-05-20").getMillis();
        assertEquals(1369008000000L, time);

    }
```

In order to make sure it is correct, you can run your unit tests (i use maven surefire plugin to run my junit test), but this argument will work on any jvm:

First try running it on one zone, e.g:

```
-Duser.timezone="Europe/Amsterdam'
```

Then try running it in another zone, e.g:

```
-Duser.timezone="Pacific/Honolulu'
```

Then your unit test should not fail in any of the cases.